# Ubuntu very slow after new installation

Tags: 18.04, drivers, nvidia, 20.04

After installing Nvidia drivers I've had the "Stopping User Manager for UID 121" error [like in this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/426235/how-to-solve-stopping-user-manager-for-uid-121-error-after-installing-nvidia-d) so I decided to delete everything and reinstall ubuntu 18.04 but now everything lags, if I open an application it takes few second to open it.

My system specs are:

- CPU: Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-7300HQ CPU @ 2.50GHz
- System Memory: 8GiB
- GPU: GP107M [GeForce GTX 1050 Ti Mobile]

I tried to install ubuntu 20.04 but I have the same problem, also I tried switching to xubuntu but nothing change. Now I am on ubuntu 20.04 and when I run the command `htop` in a terminal I can see that the command `/usr/lib/xorg/Xorg` is taking a lot of CPU (please see the image below for more details)

[image]

maybe this is something related to my Nvidia drivers ? In the `Software and Updates` application in `Additional Drivers` section I checked `Using NVIDIA metapackage from nvidia-driver-440` and applied changes (see the image below for more details)

[image]

Please tell me what can I do because I am stuck for days !

Comment: are you using proprietary nvidia driver or nouveau?  try the other one.

Comment: @Nmath Actually I tried all others option in the `Additional Drivers` section

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve my problem I had to check the `acpi` kernel boot parameters.

When I tried to install ubuntu, before getting to the install menu my computer crush.So I tried to access the GRUB boot menu by pressing the shift button when my system boot, in the menu at the bottom I pressed `f6` and checked the `nomodeset` kernel boot parameter and I was able to install ubuntu but my computer was very slow after the installation. So I tried to reinstall it but this time with checking the `acpi=off` kernel boot paramater and now everything works fine. (see image below)

[image]